# How can I use jit acceleration in the code within?

Tags: python, numpy, jit, numba

I can run this code without jit acceleration:

```py
# @jit(nopython=True)
def mnc_bellman(param, kgrid, valorInit):
    import numpy as np
    # Declaramos los argumentos del problema de programacion dinamica
    alpha, delta, sigma, gamma, beta, tfp = param

    # Inicializamos objetos que vamos a necesitar
    tam = len(kgrid)
    matrizC = np.empty((tam, tam))
    valorObj = np.zeros((tam, tam))

    for i1 in range(0, tam):
        for i2 in range(0, tam):
            matrizC[i1, i2] = tfp * kgrid[i1] ** alpha \
                              + (1.0 - delta) * kgrid[i1] \
                              - kgrid[i2]

    # Un indicador de posiciones de consumo positivas
    indC = matrizC <= 0
    matrizU = matrizC ** (1.0 - sigma) / (1.0 - sigma)
    matrizU[indC] = -1.e+6

    # A partir de aqui podemos inicializar el algoritmo ITERACION de la
    # funcion de VALOR
    # Establecemos cierta tolerancia en el criterio de convergencia
    tol = 1.0e-6

    # Esta variable va a guardar cuantas veces iteramos hasta cumplir con los
    # criterios de convergencia
    cont = 0

    # Tambien tenemos que establecer un error inicial que no se satisfaga
    # trivialmente en el primer paso del bucle
    error = 10

    while error > tol:
        for i2 in range(0, tam):
            valorObj[:, i2] = matrizU[:, i2] + beta * valorInit[i2]
        pos = valorObj.argmax(axis=1)
        valor = valorObj.max(axis=1)
        error = np.max(np.abs(valor - valorInit))
        valorInit = valor
        cont += 1
        print(error)

    # Ahora reconstruimos las reglas de decision
    reglaK = kgrid[pos]
    reglaC = tfp * kgrid ** alpha + (1.0 - delta) * kgrid - reglaK

    return valor, reglaK, reglaC
```

When I uncomment @jit, I stumble upon the following error:

"UnsupportedError: Use of unsupported opcode (IMPORT_NAME) found"

I hope somebody can orient me in this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This would work

```
import numpy as np
from numba import jit

@jit(nopython=True)
def mnc_bellman(param, kgrid, valorInit):
    # Declaramos los argumentos del problema de programacion dinamica
    alpha, delta, sigma, gamma, beta, tfp = param

    # Inicializamos objetos que vamos a necesitar
    tam = len(kgrid)
    matrizC = np.empty((tam, tam))
    valorObj = np.zeros((tam, tam))

    for i1 in range(0, tam):
        for i2 in range(0, tam):
            matrizC[i1, i2] = (
                tfp * kgrid[i1] ** alpha + (1.0 - delta) * kgrid[i1] - kgrid[i2]
            )

    # Un indicador de posiciones de consumo positivas
    indC = matrizC <= 0
    matrizU = matrizC ** (1.0 - sigma) / (1.0 - sigma)
    matrizU[indC] = -1.0e6

    # A partir de aqui podemos inicializar el algoritmo ITERACION de la
    # funcion de VALOR
    # Establecemos cierta tolerancia en el criterio de convergencia
    tol = 1.0e-6

    # Esta variable va a guardar cuantas veces iteramos hasta cumplir con los
    # criterios de convergencia
    cont = 0

    # Tambien tenemos que establecer un error inicial que no se satisfaga
    # trivialmente en el primer paso del bucle
    error = 10

    while error > tol:
        for i2 in range(0, tam):
            valorObj[:, i2] = matrizU[:, i2] + beta * valorInit[i2]
        pos = valorObj.argmax(axis=1)
        valor = valorObj.max(axis=1)
        error = np.max(np.abs(valor - valorInit))
        valorInit = valor
        cont += 1
        print(error)

    # Ahora reconstruimos las reglas de decision
    reglaK = kgrid[pos]
    reglaC = tfp * kgrid ** alpha + (1.0 - delta) * kgrid - reglaK

    return valor, reglaK, reglaC
```

The error indicates that opcode for import name is not defined, you should define import statement outside the jit decorator.

Comment: As simple as that. Thanks

Comment: Please feel free to upvote and accept, if this was helpful.